Выбор (select) и вывод информации связанной с ним
Проблема в следующем: нужно при выборе юникода вывести информацию подвязанную с ним в БД! (например, название курса!)
Вообще не понимаю как это сделать, помогите!
 <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-EditCourses" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
            Edit courses
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="flush-EditCourses" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <div class="container-form mt-5 p-3 rounded">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <?php mysqli_data_seek($courses_result, 0); ?>
                      <select id="courseSelect" class="form-select" aria-label="Выберите курс">
                        <option selected disabled>Выберите курс</option>
                        <?php while ($fullcourse = mysqli_fetch_assoc($courses_result)) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $fullcourse['unique_code']; ?>">
                                <?php echo $fullcourse['unique_code']; ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

      </div>


При выборе вызывать ajax запрос на сервер, где пхп кодом лезем в БД, подставляя переданнх код, получаем ответ и возвращаем на клиента. Далее клиент на основе данных рисует ответ. Либо перекидываете пользователя на отдельную пхп страницу, где в гет параметре будет указан нужный код.
